# Controlling the amount of decimal places on fulltext search relevance score?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance

I recall doing this before but I just can't remember how I did it, so was wondering if somebody could please enlighten me?

By default you usually get scores such as `14.9236183166504` for example; how can I trim that to just 2 decimal points or none at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The score is just a floating point number so you can use [`round`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round); for example, if you want two decimal places:

```
select round(match(x) against('y'), 2) as n from ...
```

and if you want none:

```
select round(match(x) against('y')) as n from ...
```

There's also [`floor`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) and [`ceil`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) if you're looking for integers on either side of the score or [`truncate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) if you want to truncate the floating point value rather than round it.